Using oslo/password on a remix gave me a vitejs error
It looks like vitejs cannot handle some oslo dependencies, it gives me this error:
    ✘ [ERROR] No loader is configured for ".node" files: node_modules/@node-rs/argon2-darwin-arm64/argon2.darwin-arm64.node

    node_modules/@node-rs/argon2/index.js:173:36:
      173 │             nativeBinding = require('@node-rs/argon2-darwin-arm64')
          ╵                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

✘ [ERROR] No loader is configured for ".node" files: node_modules/@node-rs/bcrypt-darwin-arm64/bcrypt.darwin-arm64.node

    node_modules/@node-rs/bcrypt/binding.js:165:36:
      165 │             nativeBinding = require('@node-rs/bcrypt-darwin-arm64')
          ╵                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

11:03:31 AM [vite] error while updating dependencies:
Error: Build failed with 2 errors:
node_modules/@node-rs/argon2/index.js:173:36: ERROR: No loader is configured for ".node" files: node_modules/@node-rs/argon2-darwin-arm64/argon2.darwin-arm64.node
node_modules/@node-rs/bcrypt/binding.js:165:36: ERROR: No loader is configured for ".node" files: node_modules/@node-rs/bcrypt-darwin-arm64/bcrypt.darwin-arm64.node
    at failureErrorWithLog (/Users/enbonnet/projects/wp-remix/node_modules/vite/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1651:15)
    at /Users/enbonnet/projects/wp-remix/node_modules/vite/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1059:25
    at /Users/enbonnet/projects/wp-remix/node_modules/vite/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1527:9
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)


I'm using it only in .server.ts but anyway it gives me the error.

I'm working around it by adding these lines in my vite.config.ts file:
...
  optimizeDeps: {
    exclude: ["@node-rs/argon2-darwin-arm64", "@node-rs/bcrypt-darwin-arm64"],
  },
...

